# JavaScript preventDefault affects the children

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm writing a small script that basically toggles a submenu when a menu item is clicked.

I managed to make it work, but I have an issue, I'm using preventDefault for the function so when the parent link is clicked, the submenu is shown.

The problem is that preventDefault also affects the children and the submenu links are also non-clickable.

The website is built in wordpress so I can't modify the HTML.
Here is the code

HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-60 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-69"><a href="#" aria-current="page">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-316"><a href="/blog">AKTUELLES</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="#">KARRIERE</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-293"><a href="#">KOOPERATIONEN</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-69").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var x = document.getElementById("menu-item-69");
    x.onclick = function(){
        var y = document.getElementById("menu-item-69").querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");
        y[0].style.display = ((y[0].style.display!='block') ? 'block' : 'none')
    };
})
```

Comment: You should take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using event delegation is the best thing instead of binding tons of event handlers

```js
// reference the outer element of the menu
document.querySelector('.menu')
  // bind click event to it
  .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    //get the li where the click was located in
    var li = event.target.closest("li")
    // see if there is a submenu inside of the li
    var submenu = li.querySelector("ul")
    if (submenu) {
      // if there is, stop the event
      event.preventDefault()
      // toggle the class to show and hide the sub menu
      submenu.classList.toggle("active")
    }
  })
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none
}

.sub-menu.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-60 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-69"><a href="#" aria-current="page">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-316"><a href="/blog">AKTUELLES</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-265"><a href="#">KARRIERE</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-293"><a href="#">KOOPERATIONEN</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-298"><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

If you really want to do it your way with tons of events, you need to check to make sure that the current target is the current link.

```
var clickedLink = event.currentTarget.closest("a")
if (clickedLink === this) { event.preventDefault(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the current target of the event is your parent menu and only call preventDefault then:

```
if (event.currentTarget == yourElement) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the question at the beginning, but I did not have time to answer it, what I'm doing now ...

```js
const myMenu = document.getElementById("My-Menu")

myMenu.onclick=e=>
{
  if (e.target.tagName!=='A') return

  let following = e.target.nextElementSibling

  if (following && following.tagName === 'UL' )
  {
    e.preventDefault()
    following.style.display = (following.style.display==='none') ? 'block' : 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="My-Menu">
  <li id="menu-item-69"><a href="#" aria-current="page">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-316"><a href="/blog">AKTUELLES</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-265"><a href="#">KARRIERE</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-293"><a href="#">KOOPERATIONEN</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-298"><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```